# Tags of common words with really concrete descriptions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I wanted to ask a question about the Android [`Loader`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) (I finally solved the problem for my own). The point is that I read that the tag [loader](/questions/tagged/loader) is about Flash ActionScript 3.0 according with its description. I did a quick review and of the first 50 questions only 8 are about Flash. There are other similar cases.

What is the problem here? Should only be used the tag [loader](/questions/tagged/loader) in the context of Flash? Should avoid using the tag for being too generic? or, should change the description of the tag?

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, there should be two separate tags, [android-loader](/questions/tagged/android-loader) and [flash-loader](/questions/tagged/flash-loader).  Note that the names could be a little different based on someone with more knowledge of those technologies, but [loader](/questions/tagged/loader) is way too general and broad.